# Possible bug in Integrate: convergent integral reported divergent

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, warning-messages

```
$Version   
"8.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (October 7, 2011)"
on Windows 10
```

Consider the calculation of this integral

```
i=Integrate[ Cos[x] Exp[-t x^Sqrt[2] ], {x, 0, \[Infinity]}, 
 Assumptions -> t > 0]

Integrate::idiv: Integral of E^(-t x^Sqrt[2]) Cos[x] does not converge on {0,\[Infinity]}. >>
```

This error message is false, because the integral is safely convergent, which can be shown by the estimation

```
|i| <= Integrate[ Exp[-t x^Sqrt[2] ], {x, 0, \[Infinity]}, 
         Assumptions -> t > 0] 
= (t^(-(1/Sqrt[2])) Gamma[1/Sqrt[2]])/Sqrt[2]
```

This behaviour can be observed for algebraic as well as for trancendental exponents of `x` while rational exponents give correct results.

Comment: `Integrate[ Cos[x] Exp[-t x^Sqrt[2] ], {x, 0, \[Infinity]}, 
 Assumptions -> t > 0]` returns the input in 13.0.0 on Windows 10.

Comment: v12.2 gives the message `Integrate::idiv: Integral of E^(-t x^Sqrt[2]) Cos[x] does not converge on {0,\[Infinity]}.`

Comment: Thanks for the version's responses. I have added the version in my OP.

Comment: Would be nice to know the general answer for arbitrary power.

Comment: In "12.0.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (April 7, 2019)", `Integrate[Cos[x] Exp[-t x^Sqrt[2]], {x, 0, \[Infinity]}, 
 Assumptions -> t > 0]` returns unevaluated, suggesting that there is no closed form fo the integral.  However, `NIntegrate[Cos[x] Exp[-x^Sqrt[2]], {x, 0, \[Infinity]}]` returns `0.61952` instantaneously, so it can compute the numerical integral for different `t`'s prettyy easily.

Comment: Perhaps `LaplaceTransform` gives a workaround ?